# iCloud "Using Local Storage 0" message notification

Tags: objective-c, core-data, icloud

Is there any notification corresponding to the "Using local storage: 0" message?

### NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification gets called when there is something in iCloud but it does not seem to be called when there is nothing in iCloud and iCloud is ready.

When I already have data synced with the iCloud on one device and I connect a second device for the first time, NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification is called when iCloud is ready. But when the app launches for the first time on the first device, so when there are no transaction logs in iCloud yet, I do not get notified at all. For example, there is no way for me to prompt the user: you have no other profiles, create one. One option I have is to let the user create a profile and merge with iCloud when ready. So, the user has to enter his/her information over and over again on multiple devices.

Comment: Nope, no notification.  No sure what you mean by 'when there is something in iCloud' or 'when there is nothing in iCloud and iCloud is ready'.  Transaction logs are the only things that are ever in iCloud, and they should always exist there while the store has iCloud options set. The notification gets called when Core Data switches from the fallback store to the iCloud synced store (which is still just a local store but one synced via iCloud).  Or if you are performing a migration or adding or removing stores from the psc.